# AWS Elastic Beanstalk cron in worker environment for Node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've read the documentation from AWS regarding [worker environments and cron](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html#worker-periodictasks). That all makes sense as far as creating the cron.yaml file, but I have a couple of questions regarding the actual setup as it relates to my app. Still pretty new to AWS.

I have 3 environments in AWS EB – the production web server, staging web server, and a worker environment. They're all running node.js and I have the app deploying to the production and staging environments.

I want to set up some cron jobs to perform periodic tasks in the worker environment that do things within the production application, such as creating backups or sending user emails.

My guess is that I should set up a new Express application that I deploy to the worker environment that accepts requests such as `/backup` or `/sendEmail`, and then from within the worker environment application I make calls to the productions application to actually do the work.

Am I going about this the right way? Or would that be putting the load on my production environment rather than actually using the worker?

My lack of experience in this area makes it difficult to ask the right questions so I may not be making sense. Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the worker setup slightly. The cron.yaml file lists an endpoint that will receive a POST request within the worker application. (Nothing from your cron.yaml file will trigger anything to hit your production application). I find it easiest to create a dedicated controller in my code that receives all the POST requests indicated by the cron.yaml file. I then deploy the same code to both the web server and the worker. When the cron job runs, a POST request is sent to the endpoint you indicated in cron.yaml and your periodic task work will all happen on the worker.

Comment: Thank you @littleforest! This helps to clarify some things.

Answer (score 0):

From the [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html)

> If your application performs operations or workflows that take a long time to complete, you can offload those tasks to a dedicated worker environment. Decoupling your web application front end from a process that performs blocking operations is a common way to ensure that your application stays responsive under load.

So if you create a code that just call the production environment, you'll take no benefits.